# Different ways to give cards

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory

The question is: You have 48 cards and want to distribute them to 4 players(so everyone gets 12). How many ways are there to do so?

My idea was to take 4 cards in each step and distribute them to the players. 4!3!2!1!
You continue in this way 12 times and this should sum up to 12*4!3!2!1! possibilities, right?

Comment: A long way: Call the players South, East, North, West. There are $\binom{48}{12}$ ways to choose the cards S gets, and for each of these there are $\binom{36}{12}$ ways to choose the cards E gets, and for each of these there are $\binom{24}{12}$ ways to choose the cards N gets, for a total of $\binom{48}{12}\binom{36}{12}\binom{24}{12}$. Express in terms of factorials. We end up with the expression that Graham Kemp got far more efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 48! ways to sort the cards.  However the order of the cards each player receives doesn't matter and there are 12! ways to sort each player's cards.
$$\text{Answer}= \frac{48!}{{12}!^4}$$